# Find the heights between the distances of a walking trail

Tags: java, for-loop

We have an array of heights, representing the altitude along a walking trail. Given `start`/`end` indexes into the array, return the sum of the changes for a walk beginning at the `start` index and ending at the `end` index. For example, with the heights `{5, 3, 6, 7, 2}` and `start=2`, `end=4` yields a sum of `1 + 5 = 6`. The start end end index will both be valid indexes into the array with `start <= end`.

```
sumHeights({5, 3, 6, 7, 2}, 2, 4) => 6       
sumHeights({5, 3, 6, 7, 2}, 0, 1) => 2       
sumHeights({5, 3, 6, 7, 2}, 0, 4) => 11
```

i'm struggling to get this right, i have tried a part of this but im confused and im getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
 public int sumHeights(int[] heights, int start, int end) {        

   int total =0;   
   int difference =0;   
      for(int i=start;i<=end;i++){           
        if(heights[i] > heights[i++]){         
           difference =heights[i] - heights[i++];                  
        }else if(heights[i++] > heights[i]){         
           difference =heights[i++] - heights[i];            
        }   
        total+=difference;   
      }   
   return total;   
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You increment i in your loop thus possibly going out of bounds:

```
for(int i=start;i<=end;i++){      // here i might be last valid index, i.e. 4 in your example     
    if(heights[i] > heights[i++]){    //here i might be 5 (because of i++), i.e. you'd get the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException     
       difference =heights[i] - heights[i++]; //here i might be 6 (because of another i++), i.e. you'd get the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException                 
    }else if(heights[i++] > heights[i]){     //here i might be 5, i.e. you'd get the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException    
       difference =heights[i++] - heights[i];            
    }   
    total+=difference;   
  }
```

To fix it, use:

```
for(int i=start;i<end;i++){   
int next = i + 1;     
    if(heights[i] > heights[next]){  
       difference =heights[i] - heights[next]; //assuming you mean next = i + 1 here and not next = i + 2 like in your code               
    }else if(heights[next] > heights[i]){    
       difference =heights[next] - heights[i];            
    }   
    else {
      difference = 0; //due to public demand I'll help you with this, too
    }

    total+=difference;   
  }
```

Edit: you could also make the loop  much simpler:

```
for(int i=start;i<end;i++){   
  total += Math.abs(heights[i] - heights[i+1]);  
}
```

Comment: Down voting: What if `heights[i] == heights[next]`? What happens to difference, and is the total correct?

Comment: Well, thanks for downvoting. I helped him with the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception and didn't care for the correctness of the logic.

Comment: @corlettk Fixed the answer, still voting down?

Comment: @Tom: Nope... upvoting... but I still think this kid is snotty.

Answer (score 2):

This is because

- you increment the variable `i` inside the loop. Use `i+1` instead of `i++` inside the loop. The `++` operator does not return `i+1` but rather returns `i` and assigns `i=i+1`.
- Another problem is that your `for` loop has a wrong definition for the values of `i`. If you want to return `sumHeights({11, 12}, 0, 1)` you want to run the loop just once right? If you run this loop twice `i+1` will be equal to `2` in the second run and it will throw the index out of bound exception.
- another problem is when `heights[i] == heights[i+1]` - in that case difference is not re-calculated and may be assigned in a previous loop run. You can solve it by moving `difference` variable declaration inside the loop.

Try this code:

```
 public int sumHeights(int[] heights, int start, int end) {        

   int total =0;   
      for(int i=start;i<end;i++){           
        int difference =0;   
        if(heights[i] > heights[i+1]){         
           difference =heights[i] - heights[i+1];          
        }else if(heights[i+1] > heights[i]){         
           difference =heights[i+1] - heights[i];            
        }   
        total+=difference;   
      }   
   return total;   
 }
```

Comment: Down voting: What if heights[i] == heights[next]? What happens to difference, and is the total correct?

Comment: Cheers mate. Nice explanation, by the way. Shame this little punk was only here for teh codez.

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this:

```
 public int sumHeights(int[] heights, int start, int end) {
 int sum=0;
while(start<end)
 {
   sum+=Math.abs(heights[start+1]-heights[start]);
   start++;
 }
return sum;
}
```